# Вывод таблицы в js которая получена через php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

На картинке вывод таблицы которые выводит php код.Добавил код html5 и теперь нужно чтобы эту таблицу выводил js или css.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 function funcBefore () { // функция пока загружается обычно это гифка загрузки
    $("#information").text ("Ожидание данных...") // пока идёт выходить такое сообщение 
   }

   function funcSuccess (data) { // ответ которые мы получили с php

   }




     $.ajax ({ // сам метод ajax
      url: "c.php", // куда отправлять данные 
      type: "POST", // метод отправки данных 
      data: ({}), // ничего не отправляем
      dataType: "html", // тип отправки сообщения
      beforeSend: funcBefore, // пока документ загружается эта фун выполняется
      success:  function(data){
          if(data=="00000"){


          }
          else {         

          }


      } 
     });




</script>


</body>
</html>


<?php 


$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","mybase3");// подключение к базе данных
$mysqli->query ("SET NAMES 'utf8' "); // кодировка

 function printResult ($result_set) {
while (($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc()) != false)  // расшифровываем массив 
{
   // print_r($row);

    echo $row["id"]; // вывод id
     echo " "; // пробел
    echo $row["frend"]; // френд
    echo "</br>"; // перенос строки 
}

}



$result_set = $mysqli->query("SELECT `id`, `frend` FROM  `qwe3` ORDER BY `frend` DESC "); // выбираем из таблицы id и frend и остортировываем их 


printResult ($result_set);  // вызываем функцию 


$mysqli->close();// закрытие бд
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно данные из php должны отобразиться в элементе #information ?

```
success:  function(data){
    $("#information").html(data);          
}
```

вставить вместо этого кода

```
  success:  function(data){
      if(data=="00000"){


      }
      else {         

      }


  }
```